# how to configuration logstash for json file

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash

How can Logstash determine that the system is running Windows from a log in JSON format, and subsequently determine the version of Windows?

systemType: WINDOWS、LINUX、OHTER ......

```
{
 "timestamp": "2023-03-01T06:38:46.097Z",
 "level": "INFO",
 "info": {
  "Version": "11",
  "System": "WINDOWS",
  "Application": ""
 },
 "message": "abc...."
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific, about what the Logstash is supposed to do? Parse the message and save it in the System field?

Comment: I would like to create separate indexes based on the system, and further divide them based on the version.
for example: 
index => "windwos-11"
or
index => "linuxRHEL-8"

Answer (score 0):

You can first parse your JSON data using the Logstash JSON filter plugin ([docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html)). Assuming that your JSON data was in a field called `log`, now you can access its fields with the notation `[log][info][Systen]`. At this point, you can combine the values of the `info.System` and `info.Version` fields to build the name of the output index that you provide in the Logstash Elasticsearch output plugin ([docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#_writing_to_different_indices_best_practices)). For example:

```
output {
   elasticsearch {
      index => "%{[log][info][System]}-%{[log][info][Version]}"
   }
}
```